# Link not clickable with absolute positioning and z-index

Tags: css, html, z-index

I'm making a tumblr theme and have some elements placed on the page using absolute positioning and z-index's to control what stays on top of other elements. For some reason my links have become unclickable, I changed the z-index of the div which houses to content to a high number but it does not make them clickable. I can't figure out what the fault is in the code.
Here's the CSS I have.

```
p.blogPost { text-indent: 30pt; text-align: justify;
}
p.blogTags { 
    font-family: 'Lobster Two', cursive; 
    color: #de2424;
    text-align: right;
}
body { 
    font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif; 
    margin:0px; }
h1.postTitle { 
    font-family: 'Lobster Two', cursive; 
    color: #de2424; 
}
h2.dateText {
    font-family: 'Lobster Two', cursive;
    color: #f1e8da;
}
#container { 
    width: 940px; 
    margin: auto; }
#blogContentWrapper { 
    width:940px; 
    position:relative; 
    overflow: hidden; }
#blogHeaderRibbon { position: relative; top: 20px; z-index: 3;
    }
#blogBottomRibbon { position: relative; top:-190px; z-index: 3;
    }
#dateTab { position: relative; left: -50px; top: 90px; }
#dateText { position: relative; top: -93px; left: 10px; }
#blogContent { 
    position: relative;
    top: -83px;
    width: 780px; 
    margin: auto; 
    background-image: URL('images/eggshell.jpg');
    z-index:2;
    }
#blogPostContent { 
    padding: 30px; 
    z-index: 3;
    }
```

You can view the development page here 
http://secretmblrtheme.tumblr.com

Setup a jsFiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/grngf/2/

Comment: Comment regarding abuse has been removed by enhzflep. :)

Comment: haha, that was just filler text for testing purposes locally, I forgot I'd written that there. My bad bro, didn't mean to offend anyone.

Comment: No dramas. Sorry for the public slapping. I'm guilty of leaving other similar nuggets in source code in the past. :-)

Comment: It's alright man, I appreciate all the help I get.

Comment: that's what i called sportmanship! kudos for both of you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

based on your tumblr website, your `#blogContent` z-index is -1, which is stacked under `#blogContentWrapper`.
try change it to 1, and increase other element's z-index that you want to put in front of it (if any)

Comment: Check it now, I changed it to 10, it should for a fact be on top of everything. Still not clickable.

Comment: i checked it's #blogPostContent that has z-index 10. it wont help since the container (#blogContent) is the relative one... and it's still -1. my advise: try to minimalise position (and the z-index) and try playing with margin, since i see some of the element use unecesary position attribute.. IMHO (but for now, let us focus on which z-index is needed to change).

Comment: This seems to work in making the links clickable, but then my problem arises in that I want the red ribbon on top, I was using the z-index to push the eggshell background under the ribbon.

Comment: yup no worries on that, increase #blogHeaderRibbon z-index value, which I see z-index 3 will help. (ups, nope :P...will check) 
edit: ah i see you put 11 on #blockContent.. you need to know that z-index is the value on how element will stack in the page. so put an element a bigger z-index value will bring it in front of other's lower valued element. try put z-index: 12 on #blogHeaderRibbon